# WordPress Favicon 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, performance, favicon

https://lexicon.com.au/ - This is my website, I want to speed it up. Unfortunately, Favicon issues arise.

From my GTMetrix - http://prntscr.com/klx2pu
Four favicon Error 404 arise. Weird thing is that, I have already set my favicon through WordPress customization.

Here are more detailed GTMetrix info of the site. https://gtmetrix.com/reports/lexicon.com.au/JrSzz6Uu

Please let me know what happened.

Comment: it seems your customization dint included favicon properly, all favicons are throwing 404, did you included favicon in header.php or via wp-admin?

Comment: Yes, it's already set up. Just really weird why they're all showing up 404 error

Comment: i can see in view source, its showing favicon doesnt exist https://lexicon.com.au/favicon-16x16.png, try including favicon in header.php instead of customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since wordpress 4.3 you can add a favicon or site icon from WordPress admin area. Simply go to Appearance » Customize and click on the ‘Site Identity’ tab
The site identity section in customizer allows you to change the site title, description, and control whether or not you want to display them in the header. It also allows you to upload your site icon. Simply click on the select file button and then upload the image you want to use as site icon.

Adding Favicon to Older WordPress (4.2 or below)

Comment: Didn't know about this! Thanks a lot :)